# app breaks when run on android version 4.4.2, throws Error: [ng:areq]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

When i use ionic run ,my app routes to discover.html on start which invokes DiscoverCtrl which throws the error :

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?p0=DiscoverCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

but when i route to AnsweredCtrl it loads properly and there is no issue there.
Also this happens only in versions lower than  api level 22.When i run the app in a higher version it runs smoothly and throws no error . I can't figure if it is an ionic issue or while building the app . I have tried reducing minSdk in config.xml but that didnt help either.Maybe i am making a rookie mistake. Thanks in advance for your help

**discover.controller.js**

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app.discover')
        .controller('DiscoverCtrl', DiscoverCtrl);
    DiscoverCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'ConnectivityMonitor', 'serverPath', '$stateParams', 'EndUser', '$timeout', '$compile', 'localStorageService', '$ionicHistory', 'cdnPath'];

    function DiscoverCtrl($scope,ConnectivityMonitor,serverPath,$stateParams,EndUser,$timeout,$compile,localStorageService,$ionicHistory,cdnPath) {

        var vm = this;
        ConnectivityMonitor.startWatching();
        $scope.somefunction = function(){};


    }

    })();
```

**answered.controller.js**

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.answered')
        .controller('AnsweredCtrl', AnsweredCtrl);
    AnsweredCtrl.$inject = ['ConnectivityMonitor','serverPath','$scope','QuestionService','$timeout','$compile', 'localStorageService', 'cdnPath', 'QuestionListService'];

    function AnsweredCtrl (ConnectivityMonitor,serverPath, $scope, QuestionService, $timeout, $compile, localStorageService, cdnPath, QuestionListService) {
       var vm = this;
       $scope.somefunction = function(){};
   }
})();
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('exy', [
'app.core', // contains external services
'app.discover',

'app.answered'
])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok i figured out the problem , In one of my function i was using 'let'in my for loop,so older webview didn't support let , removed it and it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown because the definition for your `DiscoverCtrl` is not correct. This can be caused by any of below reasons:

1. You are accessing the module `app.discover` without defining it first. Make sure that the module was defined before this controller definition using: `angular.module('app.discover', [])` syntax
2. Your dependencies are not correct resulting in incorrect controller definition.
3. This may also be possible if you don't specify the app name in `ng-app` directive

The probable cause should be first one. Make sure 1.) you are defining the module correctly and 2.) not defining it twice

Comment: module definition is the same as you specified ,